# React Redux - Getting state to component - Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to get the results from Redux state to a component. I am getting an error - Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function.

Here is my code with the code where I am getting error when I submit the search form.

```
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <select
....
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      users: state.Result.users
})
```

Comment: there's nothing I see that's obviously wrong, are you sure your users are there in `state.Result.users`?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors - Yes - I added a screenshot of the State tree to the question.

Comment: `console.log(state)` in `mapStateToProps`, that will show you what is in your state at that point.  (also, it looks like you are dumping the result of a request into your state, you probably want to clean that up and just add the relevant data to your redux state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the data not just users:

```
<ul>
  {users.data.map(userlist => <li key={userlist.id}>{userlist.username}</li>)}
</ul>
```

---

A better way to handle:

```
{users && users.data && users.data.map(...)}
```

This will ensure to run map only if there's users and users' data.

Or just,

```
{users.data && users.data.map(...)} // if you're sure to get users always
```

Comment: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when I use `{users.data.map(userlist => <li key={userlist.id}>{userlist.username}</li>)}`

`TypeError: users.map is not a function when I use `
`{users.map(userlist => <li key={userlist.id}>{.........`

Comment: {users && users.data && users.data.map(...)} - This worked. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your mapStatetoProps. In your store you have users.data, but you're mapping Result.users for some reason, which makes this.props.users null.

Try changing it to the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  users: state.Result.users
})
```

Comment: Thanks, When I change it - I get - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` .... Your answer makes sense though

Comment: I added an image of the tree to the question. Data is in Result > users > data

Comment: Show me the complete tree and not just the diff. I think you might need state.Result.users.data if it's stored under Results. Check your reducer and see what it maps it to.

Comment: - I added the complete tree .. Reducer has:   `case 'GET_RESULTS':
      return { ...state, users: py }`

Comment: Ok, you need users: state.Result.users.data. What you want to look for is the variable it is assigned to in combineReducers. Anyway, this should work based off your updated image.

Comment: `state.Result.users.data` brings me back to the error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.... And yes, I have a store.js with combinereducers and I had added it as `const reducers = combineReducers({  Result
})`

Comment: Do this: In your mapStateToProps, console.log(state) and look at it in the console to see what it outputs. That's the structure you want to use. Paste that here as well.

Comment: Only `state.Result.users` lets me get past this error but the I get the error in my question after that..

Comment: Your original example had state.Results.users. I think you need state.Result.users. Try that as well.

Comment: Yep, I have it as `state.Result.users` and get the same error in the original question.